# How can i create an even number of groups with an od number of elements USING PHP

Tags: php, html

The goal of this program is to form a number n_group of groups with a number n names per group.

This is the code prototype that i am using to solve the problem:

- first i start a session:

  ```
  <?php
  session_start();
  ?>
  ```
- created a form so the user can isert the names so i can create the groups later

```
`<form method="post" action="index.php" class="input1">
            <div>
                <input type="text" name="name_in" id="name_in" placeholder="Inserisci il nome" autocomplete="off" />
                <button type="submit">Invia</button>
            </div>
        </form>
```

- created a selection menu so the user could select the number of groups

```
`<form method="post" action="index.php" class="input2">
            <div>
                <label for="nog">Seleziona il numreo di gruppi</label>
                <select name="nog" id="nog">
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                    <option value="3">3</option>
                    <option value="4">4</option>
                    <option value="5">5</option>
                    <option value="6">6</option>
                    <option value="7">7</option>
                    <option value="8">8</option>
                    <option value="9">9</option>
                    <option value="10">10</option>
                </select>
                <button type="submit">Invia</button>
            </div>
        </form>
```

HERE I START THE FORST PART OF THE PROBLEM WHITCH IS TO DISPLAY THE NAME AS AN ORDERED LIST SO I DID THIS

- first i controllel if the session was already set and if not i assigned it as an array:

```
`if (!isset($_SESSION["list"])) {
                $_SESSION["list"] = [];
 }
```

- if the user submitted data and the data was set i pushed it into the session array:

  ```
  `if ($_POST and isset($_POST["name_in"])) {
                  array_push($_SESSION["list"], $_POST["name_in"]);
              }
  ```
- i shuffled the array since the grouping hould be casual:

  ```
  `shuffle($_SESSION["list"]);
  ```
- finally i displayed it as an ordered list:

```
`echo "<ol>";
            for ($i = 0; $i < count($_SESSION["list"]); $i++) {
                echo "<li>" . $_SESSION["list"][$i] . "</li>";
            }
            echo "</ol>";
```

THEN I STARTED THE SECOND PART: DIVIDING THE NAMES IN GROUPS

- first i check i ìf the user submits the number of groups, if not i set the n_group variable to the value 1

```
`if (isset($_POST["nog"])) {
                $n_group = $_POST["nog"];
            } else {
                $n_group = 1;
            }
```

- i need three variables to cycle freely in the variable

  - starting counter: indicates the startin point which varies based on the group that we are considering
  - end counter: it works just like the starting counter
  - member varible: corrispond to the minimum number of members per group (total number of members / number of goups) the result of the operation is given as an integer for obvious reasons

```
`$counter_start = 0;
 $counter_end = intdiv(count($_SESSION["list"]), $n_group);
 $member = intdiv(count($_SESSION["list"]), $n_group);
```

- if the total number of members and the number of groups are multiples of each other the problem is simpe to solve by using this code

```
`if ((count($_SESSION["list"]) % $n_group) == 0) {
                for ($i = 0; $i < $n_group; $i++) {
                    echo "<ol>";
                    for ($j = $counter_start; $j < $counter_end; $j++) {
                        echo "<li>" . $_SESSION["list"][$j] . "</li>";
                    }
                    echo "</ol><br>";

                    $counter_start += $member;
                    $counter_end += $member;
                }
            }
```

the problem is that i cant find a way to solve the grouping problem if the total number of members and the number of groups are not multiples(eg. 19 names divided in 4 groups)

how can i solve the problem?

Comment: Although you've talked us through it beautifully, most of the code here is irrelevant to the current problem: a large part of programming is about breaking a problem into pieces, so that you can think about each separately. In this case, it doesn't make a difference that the list came from user input, or even that it's stored in the session; your actual problem is "Given a list of items, how do I divide them into a given number of sets, even if they don't divide evenly?"

Comment: Why are you putting a backtick at the beginning of each code snippet?

Comment: Solve the problem with math and logic before attempting to write the code. Doodle it out on paper or a whiteboard, which might be helpful. If _you_ don't know how to solve the problem, how are you going to tell a computer how to do it?

Comment: I am trying to figure out how and where to assign than element or element's in case the module is greater than one. This results to be quite easy using logic but i cant find an efiicient way turn it into code which is quite puzzling